# Java Arrays: I want to create two arrays that hold 3 int values each

Tags: java, arrays, oop

**Objective:**
 Retrieve array defined in class Player in another class to do additional operations on the array content;

**Code so far:**

```
public class Players {

//attributes

private int [] Player1 = new int [3];
private int [] Player2 = new int [3];
private int round=Math.random();

//Constructor

public Players(int [] p1, int [] p2 ){
[] player1 = [] p1
[] player2 = [] p2
}
```

**Problem specification :** Does not compile;

Comment: I could be wrong, but I have a feeling you are not following OOP standards.  You should make a `Player` class then instantiate two instances of it for player1/2 in a main method.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-to-declare-an-array-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple syntax as well as type mismatch issues

**1)** Java is case sensitive

```
public Players(int [] p1, int [] p2 ){
 Player1 =  p1;
 Player1 =  p2;
}
```

So

```
Player1 !=player1
```

**2)** And

```
[] player1 = [] p1
```

Is not a valid java syntax

**3)** Finally  `Math.random()`  returns `double`, Change it as

```
double random = Math.random();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to separate the parameters trough a comma

```
public Game(int[] p1, int[] p2) {
```

And this isn't even close to working (note the lack of semicolons as well):

```
[] player1 = [] p1
[] player2 = [] p2
```

You want to set the instance fields equal to the given parameters, but there's no need to redefine that they're arrays.

Instead use this:

```
this.player1 = p1;
this.player2 = p2;
```

Keep in mind naming conventions: fields start with lowercase (so `player1` instead of `Player1`). Java is case sensitive so `Player1` and `player1` are not the same. Exactly one of the reasons why naming conventions exist.

Lastly: `Math.random` returns a `double`. If you cast it to an `int` you will lose its purpose (it returns a value between 0 and 1, if you cast it to int you will lose everything between those two boundaries). Instead make it as such:

```
private double round = Math.random();
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, you might want to consider structuring your class like this:

```
public class Player {
    //attributes
    private int[] roundValues; 
    private double round=Math.random(); //not sure what you are using this for

    //Constructor
    public Player(int[] roundValues){
        this.roundValues = roundValues;
    }

    // use this to get the roundValues array
    public int[] getRoundValues() {
        return roundValues;
    }

    // use this to change the roundValues array
    public void setRoundValues(int[] roundValues) {
        this.roundValues = roundValues;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array1 = {1,2,3}; //just some dummy values
        Player player1 = new Player(array1); 
        // do this to get the player's round values
        int[] roundVals = player1.getRoundValues();
    }
}
```

Comment: The arrays are supposed to hold the round value in the arrays. I want  then to call the array from another class.

Comment: @user3061322 ok I will update my answer so that you can do that

Comment: @turbo just through getters and setters in there;

Answer (score 0):

There is several mistakes with you program.
Check the one below:

```
public class Players {

    //attributes
    private int [] player1 = new int [3]; // use names with lowercase at beginning (convention)
    private int [] player2 = new int [3];
    private double round = Math.random();

    //Constructor
    public Players(int[] p1,  int[] p2) { // you missed a comma and a parenthesis
        player1 = p1; // no need to say again that they are arrays. add ';' at the end
        player2 = p2;
    } 

    // you could need to add these to access your private arrays from an other class
    public int[] getPlayer1(){
        return player1;
    }

    public int[] getPlayer2(){
        return player2;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

- Watch out for case sensitivity by **player1** and **Player1**.
- add some semicolons
- remove some braces for setting array variables
- the **Math.random()** method returns a double, not an integer
- variables should begin with lower case letters

Like this:

```
public class Players {

    //attributes

    private int[] player1 = new int[3];
    private int[] player2 = new int[3];
    private double round = Math.random();

    //Constructor

    public Players(int[] p1, int[] p2) {
        player1 = p1;
        player2 = p2;
    }
}
```